# Combinação de números

Tags: php, combinações

Estou tentando, sem sucesso, modificar esse script. 
Desejo que ele faça combinações deste modo.:

> 12345
>   12678 
>   ...

e não como ele faz agora:

> 12345
>   12346
>   12347
>   12348
>   ...

Segue o código:

```
<?php
class Combinations implements Iterator
{
    protected $c = null;
    protected $s = null;
    protected $n = 0;
    protected $k = 0;
    protected $pos = 0;

    function __construct($s, $k) {
        if(is_array($s)) {
            $this->s = array_values($s);
            $this->n = count($this->s);
        } else {
            $this->s = (string) $s;
            $this->n = strlen($this->s);
        }
        $this->k = $k;
        $this->rewind();
    }
    function key() {
        return $this->pos;
    }
    function current() {
        $r = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->k; $i++)
            $r[] = $this->s[$this->c[$i]];
        return is_array($this->s) ? $r : implode('', $r);
    }
    function next() {
        if($this->_next())
            $this->pos++;
        else
            $this->pos = -1;
    }
    function rewind() {
        $this->c = range(0, $this->k);
        $this->pos = 0;
    }
    function valid() {
        return $this->pos >= 0;
    }

    protected function _next() {
        $i = $this->k - 1;
        while ($i >= 0 && $this->c[$i] == $this->n - $this->k + $i)
            $i--;
        if($i < 0)
            return false;
        $this->c[$i]++;
        while($i++ < $this->k - 1)
            $this->c[$i] = $this->c[$i - 1] + 1;
        return true;
    }
}


foreach(new Combinations("1234567", 5) as $substring)
    echo $substring, ' ';

?>
```

Comment: uma combinação aleatória ao invés de sequencial?

Comment: a sequencia de números desejada não é suficiente para que se possa traçar uma lógica. Qual seria o terceiro número da sequencia?

Comment: Os números são sempre uma sequência, que pode ser 10, 20, 30... Eles seriam combinados de 5 em 5.

Comment: O objetivo é fazer com que todos os números sejam combinados entre si, de 3 em 3, com o mínimo possível de repetições, mas distribuídos de 5 em 5.

No 1º exemplo, abaixo, que é o que faz o script, há muitas repetições, porque ele toma por base inicial três dígitos - 1, 2 e 3. Isso aumenta desnecessariamente as combinações, de 3 em 3, como desejo.

1 2 3 4 5 -
1 2 3 4 6 -
1 2 3 5 6 -
1 2 4 5 6 -
1 3 4 5 6 -
2 3 4 5 6 -

Abaixo, estão combinações como desejo que fiquem. A base inicial é 1,2. Ou 12 345... e não 123 45, como acima.

1,2,3,4,5 -
1,2,6,7,8 -
1,3,6,7,8 -
2,3,4,5,6 -